# (Done) Re-Open How to Respond to a Sexual Harrassment Claim made Against You

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Not really sure why [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122379/how-to-respond-to-a-sexual-harrassment-claim-made-against-you) was closed. The OP isn't looking for anything company specific, they just want to know how to proceed.

There are already 3 re-open votes. Can we get 2 more?

Comment: It started as a question about sexual harrassment that allegedy took place in a stair case and, after multiple edits, ended up asking about religous harrasment that took place in a corridor. Most of the comments and answers were related to the first iteration. I didn't vote to close, but I can see the confusion.

Comment: And it's already accumulating close votes again.... I wonder why.  No, actually, I don't